# Remove borders of All Tables in Word Document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop

I am trying to remove border of all tables in my word document. I could think of the possible code below, seems to be right. But doesnt work. Any idea why?

```
foreach (Word.Table wordTable in wordDocument.Content.Tables) {
                    wordTable.Range.Select();
                    wordTable.Range.Borders.Enable = 0;

                }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can't share the word document, can you?

Comment: Nope sorry, confidential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (Word.Table wordTable in wordDocument.Content.Tables) 
{
    Word.Border[] borders = new Word.Border[6];
    borders[0] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft];
    borders[1] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight];
    borders[2] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop];
    borders[3] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom];
    borders[4] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal];
    borders[5] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical];

    foreach (Word.Border border in borders)
    {
        border.LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
    }
}
```

You can also do this:

```
foreach (Word.Table wordTable in wordDocument.Content.Tables) 
{
    wordTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone; 

wordTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;

 }
```

Comment: enabling or disabling borders must be at the cells level that's why your code doesnt work. Please try my edited code

Comment: It makes no different whether table borders are applied at the cell level or the table level, wordTable.Borders.Enable = 0; will remove them all.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and saw that not all the borders are removed. I don't know the reason for that.

Please try this. It works for me:

```
    foreach (Word.Table wordTable in wordDocument.Content.Tables)
    {
        wordTable.Borders.Enable = 0;
    }

    wordDocument.Save();
```

Comment: @MurtuzaHusain It works for me though. Naive question: Do you save the document after editing?

Comment: Yes, I am Saving it!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Word.Table outerwordTable in wordDocument.Content.Tables) {
                foreach (Word.Table wordTable in outerwordTable.Tables) {
                    Word.Border[] borders = new Word.Border[6];
                    borders[0] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft];
                    borders[1] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight];
                    borders[2] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop];
                    borders[3] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom];
                    borders[4] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal];
                    borders[5] = wordTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical];

                    foreach (Word.Border border in borders)
                    {
                        border.LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
                    }
                }


            }
```

This thing worked....Seems that there was another nesting level of tables somehow generated in my code